# How to count occurencies of two dependent columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with problem I have in mysql.

So I have table with tennis results structured like this:

```
W1 | L1 | W2 | L2 | W3 | L3 | W4 | L4 | W5 | L5
------------------------------------------------
 6   7    6    1    7    6
 6   1    6    1
 5   7    6    7
 6   1    7    5    6    7    6    7    7     5
```

There is max 5 sets that can be played, and every set is saved in its own column (W1- winners 1st set, L1 - losers 1st set,...).

So I want to know how many tie breaks winner won and lost. 
Tie break is every occurence where Wx and Lx are in 7-6 or 6-7 relation.

I know how to get all rows with at least one tie break, but as one row (match) can have many tie breaks, I have problem with counting it. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "So I have table with tennis results structured like this: " Yes. Fix that. See normalisation.

Comment: Do you have an advice for tennis results structure?

Comment: You're confusing data storage with data retrieval and display. A typical structure might be: `match_id, set_no, player1_score, player2_score`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i think we didn't understand each other. We could talk about database structure if I'm making database model from the scratch, but I have received this sql and need to do some analysis, so I have to get maximum from this situation...

Comment: I think we've understood each other perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your table schema is not the greatest. A better schema would be:

```
Match | Set  | W | L
---------------------
  1      1     6   7
  1      2     6   3
  1      3     5   7
  1      4     3   6
  2      1     6   7
  2      2     6   7
  2      3     6   2
  2      4     3   6
```

Then your query would be:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM <table> WHERE (W=6 AND L=7) OR (W=7 AND L=6)
```

So, we can cheat by getting your table to look something like the one above via SQL and then use that SQL as a subquery in the SQL above. To get yours to look like mine:

```
SELECT 1 as set, W1 as W, L1 as L FROM <table>
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  W2 as W, L2 as L FROM <table>
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, W3 as W, L3 as L FROM <table>
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, W4 as W, L4 as L FROM <table>
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, W5 as W, L5 as L FROM <table>
```

Combining them:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT 1 as set, W1 as W, L1 as L FROM <table>
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  W2 as W, L2 as L FROM <table>
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, W3 as W, L3 as L FROM <table>
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, W4 as W, L4 as L FROM <table>
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, W5 as W, L5 as L FROM <table>
) as unionSub
WHERE (W=6 AND L=7) OR (W=7 AND L=6)
```

Perhaps you can make a view out of that Union query and use it in the future to refer to this table since I would imagine you'll end up using it often.

Answer (score 1):

when you have lemmons make lemmonade. this isnt preaty but maybe help you get there.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9be5b/1)**

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN `W1` = 7 and `L1` = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN `W2` = 7 and `L2` = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN `W3` = 7 and `L3` = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN `W4` = 7 and `L4` = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN `W5` = 7 and `L5` = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as Winner_break_won,
      CASE WHEN `W1` = 6 and `L1` = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN `W2` = 6 and `L2` = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN `W3` = 6 and `L3` = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN `W4` = 6 and `L4` = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN `W5` = 6 and `L5` = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  as Winner_break_lost
FROM tennis
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Winner_break_won | Winner_break_lost |
|------------------|-------------------|
|                1 |                 1 |
|                0 |                 0 |
|                0 |                 1 |
|                0 |                 2 |
```